# Why PIC to PIC trhough MAX232 not working?

Tags: c, serial-port, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm trying to make a connection between 2 PICs, and a computer which works perfect in proteus but it has some problems in the real life.

The goal is to communicate multiple (4 max) RS232 devices to a computer trough an interface which concentrates all channels in one as shown in the image.

[image]

It has to be done with MAX232 because the environment is so noisy.

Question: Why is the PIC to PIC through MAX232 not working?

I have built couple of devices as I said, and both work properly when I connect them individually to the hyperterminal on the PC.

[image]

But not when I connect them to each other... I've tried switching the TX and RX (DB-9:2,3) pins but it never worked. Actually, in some of the tests, the master got stuck.

Should I put couple of pull UPS on the RX and TX?

Also pull UPS to avoid the initial floating state witch happens before the pin set up? Is it dangerous? What value?

You can download the project and all the pictures an schematics [from this link.](https://mega.nz/#!TxV3QArC!uqy1tq60LWeA1xtD4vg2Be3BIojndo_4C0V2LwO5eRY)

Thanks in advance!

The code

Master:

```
#include <18f448.h>
#fuses HS,NOPROTECT,NOWDT

#use delay(clock=20M)

#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C6,rcv=PIN_C7,bits=8, STREAM=COM_A)
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C4,rcv=PIN_C5,bits=8, STREAM=COM_B) 
int rx;

#int_RDA                              

void RDA_isr()
{
    rx=getc(COM_A);    

    fprintf(COM_A,"%X\n\r",rx); 
    fprintf(COM_B,"%X\n\r",rx);
}

void main() { 
   enable_interrupts(INT_RDA);    
   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);  
}
```

Slave:

```
#include <16F84.h> 
#fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT 
#use delay(clock=4000000)  
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_A1,rcv=PIN_A0,bits=8)  
unsigned int rx; 

void main ()
{  
    set_tris_b(0b00000000);
    set_tris_a(0b00000001); 

    while (1) { 
        rx = getc();    
        printf("%X", rx);  
        rx = ~rx;
        output_b(rx);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? Look at the lines.

Comment: Step 1 For each physical port, tie pin 2,3 to each other (and nothing else) and see if the port can talk to itself.  This will help discern if the issue or SW or HW.

Comment: RS232 was fine until it was decided that devices need to be classed as DTE or DCE. But as devices became more sophisticated they became harder to classify, leading to the situation where you need to look up which are the TX and RX (and handshake) pins. The sane way (to me) is to always have a crossover, so pin 2 is wired to pin 3. That allows any device to be connected to any other device. As for pullups, it depends where they are - a line driver may have an inverter.

Comment: Besides the oscilloscope, a breakout box is a handy piece of kit for patching, and seeing the line level.

Comment: As for noise, your picture seems to show an unshielded rs232 cable.

Comment: Try a full null-modem.  i.e. 2-3, 4-6, 7-8.  Maybe your system has been set up for a hardware handshake.  If that doesn't work, 4 to 6 & 1 and the same the other way round.